# NoMethodError: undefined method `create_booking'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User, Account and Booking Model. The Account and Booking `belongs_to :user` and User `has_one :account` and `has_many :bookings`

The problem is, I can run the method `User.create_account`, but when I run `User.create_booking` it gives me an `NoMethodError: undefined method`create_booking'`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Provide source code, and the stacktrace/error log. We can onlyguess what is happening in your application if you dont provide anything. Check [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

`create_account` is defined because it is a has_one association. For a has_many, you would want `bookings.create`.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference for a full list of association methods.